# Measurable sets properties

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-sets

I am trying to show the two following properties of measurable sets:

(i) If $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ is measurable, then for each $0\leq r \leq |E|$, there is $F \subset E$ measurable such that $|F|=r$.

(ii) Let $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a measurable set, of finite measure. Show that for each $n \in \mathbb N$, there are $n$ disjoint subsets of $E$,$(E_j)_{1\leq j \leq n}$, such that $|E_j|=\dfrac{|E|}{n}$ for all $j$.

I am pretty lost in both items, I've seen some properties of measurable sets but I don't know which could be useful to show each of these properties. I would appreciate suggestions or hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will attempt to give you hints without giving away the entire solution. Please let me know if I give too much / too little advice.

(i) Let $B_r$ denote the open ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Consider the function $f(r) = |B_r \cap E|$ (I suppose that $| \cdot |$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of a set). Show that $f$ is continuous.

(ii) Use the continuity of the same function $f$ above to derive this conclusion as well.

Hopefully this will give a nudge in the right direction!

Comment: I am still somewhat lost, in i) I've tried to use the continuity and it made me think of the intermediate value theorem, but I am not so sure if this is the direction. In ii) I couldn't use your hint.

Comment: Yes! Use the intermediate value theorem. Once you have (i) settled, then you can also use the intermediate value theorem in (ii).

Comment: In (ii) I can use (i) to affirm that there is $r>0$ such that $|A \cap B(0,r)|=|A|$, I divide this ball in $n$ disks of the same radius $D_j$ so that $A \cap B(0,r)=\cup_{j=1}^n A \cap D_j$. I don't know how to show that each $A_j=A \cap D_j$ has the required measure. In fact, I am pretty sure this is not the case, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: You're right: dividing the ball into equal-sized disks isn't helpful. But as the radius $r$ of $B_r$ increases, you should get subsets $A \cap B_{r_1}$ of measure $|A|/n$, $A \cap B_{r_2}$ of measure $2|A|/n$, and so forth.

Comment: Oh, so I define $A_j=(A \cap B_{r_j}) \setminus (A \cap B_{r_{j-1}})$, right?

Comment: Careful: there are unbounded sets of finite measure. But either way, the limit as $r$ goes to infinity should be $|A|$.

Comment: Sorry, I've just deleted my comment because I've realized this and I didn't see your answer, thank you!